# Transforming the value of a ReplaySubject

Tags: rx-java

Clever Java people! I'm slow and stuck this morning and I hope that you can help. (I'm not new to streams and programming, but very new to Java and Rx)

Essentially, I have a simple object, Credentials, with a userName property. I receive this as a ReplaySubject and I want to convert that to a ReplaySubject instead. I.e. basically just transform the ReplaySubject to a ReplaySubject. This is code that expresses what I want, but it errors with type error that overwhelms to poor cognitive functions that are not yet used to Java.

```
 public ReplaySubject<String> getUserId() {
   return getCredentials(context).map(credentials -> credentials.userName);
 }

 private ReplaySubject<Credentials> getCredentials() {
```

The error:

```
Error:(52, 43) error: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Observable<R> conforms to ReplaySubject<String>
where R,T are type-variables:
R extends Object declared in method <R>map(Func1<? super T,? extends R>)
T extends Object declared in class Observable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that error message indeed makes the problem sound more complicated than it actually is.

The main point is: `map` returns an `Observable`, not a `ReplaySubject`. (Even if the original `Observable` that you called `map` on was actually a `ReplaySubject`.)

However, that's not really a problem, just change the return type of `getUserId` to `Observable<String>`. The underlying `ReplaySubject` will still replay all the values to each new subscriber.

Try this:

```
package com.example;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.functions.Func1;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;
import rx.subjects.ReplaySubject;

public class ReplaySubjectTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ReplaySubject<Integer> originalSubject = ReplaySubject.create();

        Observable<Integer> doubledObservable = originalSubject.map(new Func1<Integer, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call(Integer integer) {
                return integer * 2;
            }
        })
                .doOnNext(new LoggingAction1<Integer>("after doubling"));

        originalSubject.onNext(1);

        doubledObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new LoggingSubscriber<Integer>("1"));

        originalSubject.onNext(2);
        originalSubject.onNext(3);

        doubledObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new LoggingSubscriber<Integer>("2"));

        // wait for two seconds before stopping main thread
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot to mention: You'll need to replace my own LoggingSubscriber and LoggingAction with your own...

Also: Do you really wnat a `ReplaySubject` (that replays all previous values) or would a `BehaviourSubject` (that replays only the most recent value) be enough?

**EDIT 2:** If you anticipate that the `Credentials` (and therefore the UserId) will change often during the lifetime, it may be better to use a `BehaviourSubject` instead of the `ReplaySubject`. This way each `Subscriber` will only get the latest UserId right away as well as any subsequent new UserIds. With a `ReplaySubject` you would also get *all previous* UserIds, and the `onNext` of your `Subscriber` will be called in quick succession for values that may not even be relevant any more. This may not be a problem if you just update a local UI with the new UserId. But it may be more problematic, if you are going to load the *list of recently watched movies* (or something) for each new UserId - this would trigger a lot of network requests, only the last of which would be interesting to you.

I hope this makes some sense...

One more thing: I'm not too familiar with how Promises in JavaScript, but are you sure you need a `Subject` at all here? Did you have a look at simpler methods of creating `Observables`, like `just` or `defer`?

Comment: Thanks a ton, just changing the signature of getUserId did indeed work.

Comment: BehaviourSubject might be enough. I'm basically trying to emulate the behaviour of a Promise in JavaScript. Are the any particular disadvantages to using ReplaySubject instead of BehaviorSubject?